# Order posts by the date they were liked not the posted one (two tables) MySql

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables

```
table_posts: id_post | post | date_post
table_likes: id_like | id_post | date_like
```

I want to show posts ordered by `date_like`

I tried using `JOIN` but it doesn't retrieve the results expected in `phpmyadmin` (duplicates)

```
SELECT m. * 
FROM table_posts AS m
JOIN table_likes AS p ON p.id_post = m.id_post
WHERE (m.id_post =35 OR m.id_post =36) /*both posts were liked*/
ORDER BY p.date_like DESC
```

How do I retrieve the posts ordered by the date they were liked?

Comment: It looks like you are already doing it with the clause `ORDER BY p.date_like DESC`. If you need to retrieve also the value, add to the SELECT the field: `SELECT m.*, p.date_like FROM ...`

Comment: Thanks you. It just add a column to the results. The problem is the results shown are duplicates!

Comment: I fixed the duplicates. thanks you. the code works perfect now :)